# How to save my BitLocker recovery key to my personal Microsoft account, when there is a domain account connected?

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker, disk-encryption, cloud

I want to encrypt some personal hard drives with BitLocker on Windows 10, and save the recovery keys to my personal Microsoft account, which is the one I connect to Windows with.

The problem is that I have also connected my university's domain account, and BitLocker will only let me save the key to this uni account : the "Save to Microsoft account" option in the BitLocker setup window has been replaced with "Save to your cloud domain account", and when I select this, the key doesn't appear in my Microsoft account's recovery keys list, which I assume means that the key has been sent to my uni's network instead.

These keys are for personal drives and I want to save them to my personal account. I don't want to remove the domain account entirely as it's convenient. How can I choose which account to save the BitLocker recovery keys to ?

Comment: To my knowledge you cannot connect a domain account to a Microsoft Account.  Wouldn't it be easier to just save the recovery keys as a text file to your OneDrive account?  An alternative is to create a local account, connect that to the Microsoft Account, then backup the recovery keys that way.

Comment: Well, that's a stupid situation Microsoft puts me in... I just want BitLocker to work like before I connected this domain account. As for "connecting a domain account to a Microsoft account", I didn't said I did that, and I don't even know what that could exactly mean. I just meant that I added this domain account to Windows as a professional Exchange account.

Comment: In order to store your recovery key to your MS account you have to link your local profile to your Ms account

Comment: I did that. I linked my Windows account to my Microsoft account, then I added a domain account from my uni as a "professional account" to connect to things like email, calendar, contacts, OneDrive, Office... And now only the domain account can store my BitLocker keys, despite the fact that the Microsoft account is still linked.

Comment: Answer for the person who suggested removing the `exchange` tag : the domain account I'm talking about was added as an Exchange account, so I think there is a link.

Comment: Tag describes similar but entirely different exchange but, alright...

Answer (score -1):

For me what worked was going to the Settings app > Accounts > Access work or school, and then selecting the option to disconnect my work/school account. Once I did that, Bitlocker gave me the option to save to my Microsoft account. Once I enabled Bitlocker, I could then go back to Settings and reconnect my work/school account.

Comment: " I don't want to remove the domain account entirely as it's convenient. How can I choose which account to save the BitLocker recovery keys to ?"

Comment: Yeah but is OP signed into the computer a Microsoft account or domain account? If it's just a Microsoft account, removing and then readding the domain account should do the trick and shouldn't take that much work at all. For me the above worked, but for the OP's situation, it might not.